# About FAPAR calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, remote-sensing

I want to calculate FAPAR in different land cover types using max and min value of NDVI.

I have a raster image with 9 Land cover types and max, min value of NDVI in each land cover type but I don't know the way how to calculate it in different LC types from NDVI image.

- What kind of function can be used to do this?
- What software is more useful for this kind of calculation?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of fAPAR is that it is a replacement for NDVI, and not something which is derivable from an existing NDVI image. You can find [FAPAR scenes](http://fapar.jrc.ec.europa.eu/WWW/Data/Pages/FAPAR_Download/FAPAR_Download_GLC2000.php) to download, otherwise you'd probably need to implement the algorithm based on per-channel scenes. I see one [student project](http://lemenkova.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/calculation-of-the-leaf-area-index-fapar.pdf) which estimated fAPAR as `fAPAR = NDVI * 1.25 – 0.025` but I'd take this calculation with a grain of salt.

For your second question of looking at the values within land cover types, you can use Zonal Statistics assuming you're sticking with ArcGIS.

Comment: +1 The student project doesn't provide any basis for that relationship.  However, Myneni & Williams in a [2004 paper](http://www.mendeley.com/research/evaluation-modis-lai-fapar-relation-between-fapar-ndvi-semiarid-environment-using-situ-measurements/) provide some (qualified) hope: "In situ fAPAR and normalised differential vegetation index (NDVI) for three different vegetation types showed a strong linear relationship... The fAPAR/NDVI relations found here, however, do not apply on a global scale but are only valid for similar sun-sensor view geometry and soil colour."